# What happens to polymers under high pressure?

Tags: organic-chemistry, pressure, physical-organic-chemistry

What happens when you have polymers under high pressure? My very sketchy thoughts of polymers are that they can be thought of tangles of carbon chains surrounded by hydrogen, but that some polymers like polyethylene can be ordered or  "crystalline".  So it seems like there could be phase transitions, or if the pressure was high enough the polymer would have to change it structure or if in a tangled structure  perhaps break links and form new links making a new polymer?

Edit: Very high pressures like those used in diamond anvil cell experiments.

Comment: You mean polyethylene specifically? Polypropylene (and some others) is similar, but most of them are not.

Comment: @Mithoron More generally, polyethylene was just something I knew could have a crystal structure

Comment: Well, lets better make it more specific... This could be pretty interesting entry here, if it won't get closed as too broad, unclear or whatever. Some quite unusual and less known things happen under high pressure.

Comment: somewhat related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/131342/c60-fullerene-polymers https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/31313/why-does-addition-polymerisation-of-high-density-polyethene-use-low-temperatur

Comment: @Mithoron Edited to be more specific to be about alkanes since they can be of different lengths and at room temperature go from being a gas to a liquid to a solid depending on the length.